# incremental AES encryption in CBC mode not working?

Tags: openssl, aes, cbc-mode, cmac

Below is the sample code from RFC4493, regarding AES 128 CMAC. When I run this code, single block encryption is correct. However if EVP_EncryptUpdate() is called multiple times, I do not get the expected result. If I call EVP_EncryptUpdate() with a buffer that is N*block_size and encrypt with a single call, I get the correct result. Everything I read says that update can be called multiple times.

What am I missing?

```
/****************************************************************/
/* AES-CMAC with AES-128 bit */
/* CMAC Algorithm described in SP800-38B */
/* Author: Junhyuk Song (junhyuk.song@samsung.com) */
/* Jicheol Lee (jicheol.lee@samsung.com) */
/****************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>

// OpenSSL includes
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

/* For CMAC Calculation */
unsigned char const_Rb[16] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x87
};
unsigned char const_Zero[16] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

/* Basic Functions */
void xor_128(unsigned char* a, unsigned char* b, unsigned char* out)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        out[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    }
}

void print_hex(char* str, unsigned char* buf, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((i % 16) == 0 && i != 0)
            printf("%s",str);
        printf("%02x", buf[i]);
        if ((i % 4) == 3)
            printf(" ");
        if ((i % 16) == 15)
            printf("\n");
    }
    if ((i % 16) != 0)
        printf("\n");
}

void print128(unsigned char* bytes)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        printf("%02x", bytes[j]);
        if ((j % 4) == 3)
            printf(" ");
    }
}

void print96(unsigned char* bytes)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        printf("%02x", bytes[j]);
        if ((j % 4) == 3)
            printf(" ");
    }
}

/* AES-CMAC Generation Function */
void leftshift_onebit(unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char overflow = 0;
    for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[i] = input[i] << 1;
        output[i] |= overflow;
        overflow = (input[i] & 0x80) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return;
}

void AES_128(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* in, unsigned char *out)
{
    int len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, NULL);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); // input and output are the same size
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, 16);
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, out, &len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();
}

void generate_subkey(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* K1, unsigned char* K2)
{
    unsigned char L[16];
    unsigned char Z[16];
    unsigned char tmp[16];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        Z[i] = 0;

    AES_128(key, Z, L);

    if ((L[0] & 0x80) == 0) { /* If MSB(L) = 0, then K1 = L << 1 */
        leftshift_onebit(L, K1);
    } else { /* Else K1 = ( L << 1 ) (+) Rb */
        leftshift_onebit(L, tmp);
        xor_128(tmp, const_Rb, K1);
    }
    if ((K1[0] & 0x80) == 0) {
        leftshift_onebit(K1, K2);
    } else {
        leftshift_onebit(K1, tmp);
        xor_128(tmp, const_Rb, K2);
    }
    return;
}

void padding(unsigned char* lastb, unsigned char* pad, int length)
{
    int j;
    /* original last block */
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        if (j < length) {
            pad[j] = lastb[j];
        } else if (j == length) {
            pad[j] = 0x80;
        } else {
            pad[j] = 0x00;
        }
    }
}

void AES_CMAC(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* input, int length,
    unsigned char* mac)
{
    unsigned char X[16], Y[16], M_last[16], padded[16];
    unsigned char K1[16], K2[16];
    int n, i, flag;
    generate_subkey(key, K1, K2);
    n = (length + 15) / 16; /* n is number of rounds */
    if (n == 0) {
        n = 1;
        flag = 0;
    } else {
        if ((length % 16) == 0) { /* last block is a complete block */
            flag = 1;
        } else { /* last block is not complete block */
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if (flag) { /* last block is complete block */
        xor_128(&input[16 * (n - 1)], K1, M_last);
    } else {
        padding(&input[16 * (n - 1)], padded, length % 16);
        xor_128(padded, K2, M_last);
    }

    int len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, NULL);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); // input and output are the same size

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        X[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        xor_128(X, &input[16 * i], Y); /* Y := Mi (+) X */
        // AES_128(key, Y, X); /* X := AES-128(KEY, Y); */
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, X, &len, Y, 16);
    }
    xor_128(X, M_last, Y);
    // AES_128(key, Y, X);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, X, &len, Y, 16);
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, X, &len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        mac[i] = X[i];
    }
}

/*
    Following is the expected output:
            --------------------------------------------------
            Subkey Generation
            K
            2b7e1516 28aed2a6 abf71588 09cf4f3c
            AES-128(key,0) 7df76b0c 1ab899b3 3e42f047 b91b546f
            K1
            fbeed618 35713366 7c85e08f 7236a8de
            K2
            f7ddac30 6ae266cc f90bc11e e46d513b
            --------------------------------------------------
            --------------------------------------------------
            Example 1: len = 0
            M
            <empty string>
            AES-CMAC
            bb1d6929 e9593728 7fa37d12 9b756746
            --------------------------------------------------
            Example 2: len = 16
            M
            6bc1bee2 2e409f96 e93d7e11 7393172a
            AES-CMAC
            070a16b4 6b4d4144 f79bdd9d d04a287c
            --------------------------------------------------
            Example 3: len = 40
            M
            6bc1bee2 2e409f96 e93d7e11 7393172a
            ae2d8a57 1e03ac9c 9eb76fac 45af8e51
            30c81c46 a35ce411
            AES-CMAC
            dfa66747 de9ae630 30ca3261 1497c827
            --------------------------------------------------
            Example 4: len = 64
            M
            6bc1bee2 2e409f96 e93d7e11 7393172a
            ae2d8a57 1e03ac9c 9eb76fac 45af8e51
            30c81c46 a35ce411 e5fbc119 1a0a52ef
            f69f2445 df4f9b17 ad2b417b e66c3710
            AES-CMAC
            51f0bebf 7e3b9d92 fc497417 79363cfe
            --------------------------------------------------
*/
int main()
{
    unsigned char L[16], K1[16], K2[16], T[16], TT[12];
    unsigned char M[64] = {
        0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96,
        0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a,
        0xae, 0x2d, 0x8a, 0x57, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xac, 0x9c,
        0x9e, 0xb7, 0x6f, 0xac, 0x45, 0xaf, 0x8e, 0x51,
        0x30, 0xc8, 0x1c, 0x46, 0xa3, 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x11,
        0xe5, 0xfb, 0xc1, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x52, 0xef,
        0xf6, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x45, 0xdf, 0x4f, 0x9b, 0x17,
        0xad, 0x2b, 0x41, 0x7b, 0xe6, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x10
    };
    unsigned char key[16] = {
        0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6,
        0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
    };
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("K ");
    print128(key);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nSubkey Generation\n");
    AES_128(key, const_Zero, L);
    printf("AES_128(key,0) ");
    print128(L);
    printf("\n");
    generate_subkey(key, K1, K2);
    printf("K1 ");
    print128(K1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("K2 ");
    print128(K2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nExample 1: len = 0\n");
    printf("M ");
    printf("<empty string>\n");
    AES_CMAC(key, M, 0, T);
    printf("AES_CMAC ");
    print128(T);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nExample 2: len = 16\n");
    printf("M ");
    print_hex(" ", M, 16);
    AES_CMAC(key, M, 16, T);
    printf("AES_CMAC ");
    print128(T);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nExample 3: len = 40\n");
    printf("M ");
    print_hex(" ", M, 40);
    AES_CMAC(key, M, 40, T);
    printf("AES_CMAC ");
    print128(T);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nExample 4: len = 64\n");
    printf("M ");
    print_hex(" ", M, 64);
    AES_CMAC(key, M, 64, T);
    printf("AES_CMAC ");
    print128(T);
    printf("\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call EncryptUpdate more than once, but only if you use the correct cipher for your application.

That sample code is designed to have `AES_128` do *only* the AES-128 primitive, and the code explicitly performs the CBC-like (but with IV 0s) chaining. You have used `EVP_aes_128_cbc` which does the CBC-chaining operation inside EVP, thus actually cancelling the one done by the calling code and giving the wrong result if the input is more than one block. If you instead use `EVP_aes_128_ecb` (with padding off, as you already have) it will effectively give you the primitive this code as written needs. On older OpenSSL you could use the low-level interface instead to get the primitive directly, and that is arguably clearer, but in 3 up this is deprecated.

Alternatively you can modify the main part of `AES_CMAC` as follows:

```
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, const_Zero);
    // it's not documented that IV defaults to 0s and could change; safer to be explicit
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); // input and output are the same size

    // no need to initialize X
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        // DON'T xor prev block to M[i]; just pass M[i] and let EVP do it
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx,X,&len,&input[16*i],16);
        if( len!=16 ) abort();
    }
    // again DON'T xor, just pass M_last to EVP
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, X, &len, M_last, 16);
    if( len!=16 ) abort();
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, Y, &len); // doesn't actually output anything
    // but nice to follow standard pattern and show it DOESN'T change X
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();
```

The alternative you stated -- one call for all n blocks -- *shouldn't* work even for exact blocks, which not all the test cases are, because CMAC tweaks the last block. But if you have a large enough buffer, you could use the `_cbc` cipher with no padding and IV 0s, do one encrypt call on the first n-1 blocks and discard the output, then one encrypt call on the single block `M_last` and use the result from that.

Comment: Changing the code to use ECB mode works as expected. Thanks!

Using CBC mode as you demonstrated does not generate the expected result. What is really odd is that the output changes each time I run it. Like IV is not getting initialized.

Comment: Are you sure? On my system your posted code with 160-177 changed to what I posted (and everything else identical) gives both constant and correct values. You didn't also remove or change the part that computes M_last did you? That should remain the same; that's what I meant by 'main part' rather than 'whole body'. And using an unitialized M_last would give certainly wrong and possibly inconsistent results.

Comment: I would upload my code but I can not do it as a comment

Comment: Edit your question and add a new section. Comments are limited in size and formatting, and transient i.e. may be deleted.